# Symbian S30 programming - how?

Tags: mobile, symbian

As you may have seen, there is another super cheap phone (Nokia 100) which plans to sell for 25€. I'm very much into Arduino and Raspberry Pi so this got me thinking - how to develop on such phone? Is it possible to wipe out its stock OS for something entirely different and open sourced? I personally don't mind to learn S30 but is there a SDK to get somewhere? Do I have to "jailbreak" it?

In other words, is it possible to turn those super cheap phones into versatile hobbits platform like Arduino?

(Btw, Nokia if you read this - why haven't you done so already?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S30 doesn't have an SDK. Nokia's SDKs are at http://www.developer.nokia.com.

To re-flash this phone would be difficult. Often the devices have authentication mechanisms to only allow official re-flashing, otherwise branded/network locked phones would be easily bypassed.